# (WPF) Binding does not show anything in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am currently learning WPF and trying to test some binding.Here I want to bind my tab page's header with a property `fileName` in the MainWindow.xaml.cs, but it doesn't show anything

I don't see any errors in the output window either
DataContext in the `Window` tag:

`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Binding in the xaml :

`<TabItem Header="{Binding fileName, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="Header_Tab" Height="20" Width="175">`

My property:

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)

                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));

        }
...
public string filePath { get; set; }
        public string folderPath { get; set; }
        public string fileName
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != Path.GetFileName(filePath))
                {
                    value = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your fileName property setter implementation is broken. It makes no sense to set `value` in a C# property setter, as it is only an input argument that isn't used any longer. Please clarify the exact relationship of these three properties. Which ones are you going to change, and which ones do you want to show in the UI? Seems like `FolderPath` and `FileName` should be readonly, and you only want to set `FilePath`. Besides that, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the TabItem.Header Binding is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filePath` property should be implemented like this:

```
private string _filePath;
public string filePath 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _filePath;
    }  
    set
    {
        if(value != _filePath)
        {
            _filePath = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("filePath");

            // Notify the UI that it should update fileName 
            // when there is a change on filePath
            NotifyPropertyChanged("fileName");
        }
    }
}
```

And the `fileName` property should be read-only:

```
public string fileName
{
    get
    {
        return Path.GetFileName(_filePath);
    }
}
```